# How to get object from Amazon s3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm unsuccessfully trying to get uploaded image as object using next code:

```
AmazonS3Client client = SomeService.getAmazonService().getS3Client();
S3Object image = client.getObject(user.getBucketName(), user.getKey());
IOUtils.copy(image.getObjectContent(), new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\im.jpg")));
```

It was blank.

Could you point me if I'm missing some read permissions or else?

Comment: I think your code is wrong. You don't seem to be using the inputStream that you assign the stream from S3 to.

Comment: @WadeMatveyenko, yes it was extra line. btw problem wasn't with this code, it was ui issue.